# why am i getting CXX0030 (" Error: expression cannot be evaluated") and CXX0017 on almost everything?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, symbols, evaluation

it's a weird issue... cause i'm pretty much sure it worked with no problems up until a few days ago. i'm using VS2010 SP1.
when checking my Auto or Local variables debug window, i cannot seem to be able to evaluate them. even if it's a plain boolean, string or even a number variable

when hovering with the mouse on the variable during run time, after hitting a breakpoint, nothing shows up.

string show up in the watches panel as "0x0000000000000000" and when expanded shows CXX0030 under both "capacity" and "size" fields and no data.

a boolean variable is evaluated to a CXX0017 ("Error: symbol "variablename" not found")

**when displayed to the screen or console everything is ok, with all the correct data in place!** debugging is a nightmare at the moment...

i can put my finger on the cause to all of this. why is this happening?

Comment: When debugging starts, look at the Output window, whether .pdb files for your .exe and .dll are successfully loaded.

Comment: "Symbols loaded (source information stripped)"

Comment: for exe, ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KernelBase.dll, msvcr100.dll msvcp100.dll

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer isn't going to work.  This otherwise sounds like you switched to the Release configuration.